# Difference between Infinity and NaN (Not a number)

Tags: java

When does java print Infinity and when does it print NaN?

Why is 1.0/0.0 infinity but ((1.0/0.0) - (1.0/0.0)) NaN and 0.0f/0.0f an NaN?

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Well, what *is* the difference? Why would it be different to know that "something approaches infinity" and "a computation does not result in a defined value"? What does Wikipedia say: check there *first* - see Infinity and [Not a Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) articles and associated links.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Java is following known math facts.  1.0 / 0.0 is [infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity#Computing), but the others are [indeterminate forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms), which Java represents as `NaN` (not a number).

Answer (score 2):

Java's just following the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) specification, which is consistent with most floating-point hardware nowadays.

Comment: This C++-ish article is particularly informative: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx#10397012

Answer (score 1):

1.00/0 goes infinity but infinity minus infinity is not a number.

Comment: Advanced mathematics aside