# Program output is NaN instead of float

Tags: java

I am working on an exercise from a book, the exercise sounds like this:

Drivers are concerned with the mileage their automobiles get. One driver has kept track of several trips by recording the miles driven and gallons used for each tankful. Develop a Java application that will input the miles driven and gallons used (both as integers) for each trip. The program should calculate and display the miles per gallon obtained for each trip and print the combined miles per gallon obtained for all trips up to this point. All averaging calculations should produce floating-point results. Use class Scanner and sentinel-controlled repetition to obtain the data from the user.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class consumption {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int miles = 0;
        int gallons = 0;
        int totalGallons = 0;
        int totalMiles = 0;
        float mpg = 0;
        float totalAverage = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter number of gallons or enter -1 to finish:");
        gallons = in.nextInt();
        while(gallons != -1)
        {
            gallons += totalGallons;
            System.out.println("Enter the number of miles driven:");
            miles = in.nextInt();
            miles += totalMiles;
            mpg = ((float)totalMiles/totalGallons);
            System.out.printf("Total Miles per Gallon on this trip is %.2f\n", mpg);
            System.out.println("Enter number of gallons:");
            gallons = in.nextInt();
        }

        if(totalGallons!=0)
        {
            totalAverage = (float) totalMiles/totalGallons;
            System.out.printf("Total consumption on all trips is %.2f\n", totalAverage);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("You did not enter a valid gallon quantity\n");
    }
}
```

For some reason, after I enter the sentinel (-1), the output shows NaN instead of the float number it should output.

Also, it does not calculate the `totalAverage`, not even showing NaN

This is the output:

Enter number of gallons or enter -1 to finish: 25

Enter the number of miles driven: 5

Total Miles per Gallon on this trip is NaN

Enter number of gallons: -1

You did not enter a valid gallon quantity

Process finished with exit code 0

Please help me :(

Comment: You never change the value of `totalGallons` (which is 0).  Anything divided by zero is `NaN`.  You probably meant `totalGallons += gallons`, not `gallons += totalGallons` (but you have similar issues with totalMiles)

Comment: Your operands to `+=` seem to always be flipped, making the totals zeros, and their ratio always NaN.

Answer (score 2):

A `NaN` value typically arises when you divide zero by zero using floating operations.  It is short for "not a number" and is used in some contexts where a computation produces a value that is nonsensical.

(`NaN` does not represent an infinite number!  There is a different floating point value for that: `INF`).

The primitive operations that generate `NaN` values in Java are:

- `0.0 / 0.0`
- `±INF / ±INF`
- `0.0 * ±INF` and `±INF * 0.0`
- `INF + (-INF)` and `(-INF) + INF`
- `INF - (INF)` and `(-INF) - (-INF)`

Some `java.lang.Math` functions can also generate NaN values.   For example, `Math.sqrt(-1)` produces a `NaN`.

**Hint**: take a look at where you are doing the calculation of `mpg` ... and how you are calculating the two values that the expression uses.  Look at them carefully.  (And check your lecture notes on what `+=` actually does!)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the while loop, you write the statements

```
gallons += totalGallons;
miles += totalMiles;
```

but `totalGallons` is initialized as 0 and its value never changes. The same is for `totalMiles`. Therefore the calculation for `mpg`

```
mpg = (float) totalMiles / totalGallons;
```

takes the form of

```
(float) 0/0;
```

which is `infinity`. In Java, `infinity` for `float` values is represented as `Nan : Not a number`. So just change the statements to

```
totalGallons += gallons;
totalMiles += miles;
```

---

### EDIT

As the others have said, `infinity` is not `Nan`. There's a difference between when Java displays `INF` and when `Nan`. Refer to this question for more info: [Difference between infinity and not-a-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213819/difference-between-infinity-and-nan-not-a-number).

Also, check @StephanC's answer on the cases where JAVA produces `Nan`.

Comment: Incorrect.  NaN does not represent infinity.  The value for infinity in floating point is displayed as INF.

Comment: @StephenC Oh. Didn't know that specifically. Well, is `Nan` some kind of an equivalent to `Not a number` stuff of which `infinity` is a kind?

Comment: Infinity and NaN are different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213819/difference-between-infinity-and-nan-not-a-number

Comment: No.  See my answer.

Comment: *"is Nan some kind of an equivalent to Not a number?"* See javadoc of [Double.NaN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN): *A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type double.*

Comment: Doubly incorrect.  Infinity is defined, even through it is not a number.  The result of division is not defined (and hence also not a number)